# Error in Elliptic Curve JavaScript library: Signature without r or s?

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-signature, verify, elliptic-curve

I want to receive a signed message `hello` with Elliptic curve signature and verify it.
This code is a server side, which receives from client side a message and its signature. However, it does not verify it because there is problem in signature.
The code:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
const EC = require('elliptic').ec;
const ec = new EC('secp256k1');

var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://localhost';
var client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL);

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("MQTT connected  "+ client.connected);
    client.subscribe('BCmessage');
    client.subscribe('BCsignature');
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    if (topic === 'BCmessage'){
        var msg = message.toString();
    } else if (topic === 'BCsignature'){
        var sig = message.toString(); 
    }
    var key = ec.keyFromPublic('0473891deb0cb162c568592d806ef91eb3eab0ae0eb76b72c92d88b6c47789d1dd64b6c9aeb8c564267ed69dba205df45d6586c7907cbd5f0f5ba61291500809e0', 'hex');
    console.log(key.verify(msg, sig));
});
```

The client side:

```
let myKey = ec.keyFromPrivate('29f3c33a550d3810e6b82b7b510672118aeabcf8b19e00172e4623cbf480d2b8');
const sig = myKey.sign("hello", 'base64');
var sighex = sig.toDER('hex');
client.publish("BCmessage", "hello");
client.publish("BCsignature", sighex);
```

The error:

```
  assert(options.r && options.s, 'Signature without r or s');
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined
```

I do not understand the error and how to fix it! is the problem with string/hex in signature ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I sign with your client side code and verify with the last two lines of your server side code, the verification is successful on my machine. I can reproduce the error with an invalid signature (e.g. some string instead of the hex encoded signature). Have you compared the signature (and also the message) on both sides? Maybe you are using the wrong signature on the server side and it is more a data transfer or related problem (e.g. wrong encoding/decoding; e.g. does `message.toString()` really generate the hex encoded signature?) than a signing problem.